# Adding Organization filter to Event details report

Tags: civireport, custom-reports

I have a report that I've modified from the Attendee List report under the Event Reports, but it's missing the ability to filter by organization name. Essentially, the purpose of the report is to pull out detailed information of all employees who've attended events in a defined range. This can then be used to show the company the value they are receiving by being members. Everything I need is there except the ability to display only individuals from just one company. Is there a simple way to edit the report to filter by company?

I'm running CiviCRM 4.7.11 on Joomla 3.6.5

Answer (score 1):

"Simple" is a relative term here!  This is an excellent beginner-level modification to CiviCRM's source code - but any modification requires a fair amount of knowledge.

Assuming you're using the "Current Employer" as the organization name, you're in luck.  The current employer's name is stored in the "Organization Name" field on the individual's contact.

You'll need to modify the file in `CRM/Report/Form/Event/ParticipantListing.php`.  [Check out this session](https://sf2012.civicrm.org/sessions/civicrm-reports-creating-and-extending-when-ui-isnt-enough.html) from CiviCon 2012 for a video and slides.

While it's not suitable as a learning resource, the [CiviReport Reference](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviReport+Reference) is an excellent reference document.

Comment: If you need help getting started, please join the #dev-newcomers channel at https://chat.civicrm.org!  And if you want to pay someone to do this for you, try posting in the #dev channel.

Answer (score 0):

Jon G points to great resources for defining custom reports, and there are many other answers on this SE that should point you correctly in that direction (customizing reports is great once you get the hang of it!).

I wanted to note you can also get at this information with an advanced search without customizing, if you do use "Current Employer", and if a search rather than report would work for your use-case...

In advanced search you can set...

- Events>Event Name = "The events you want to filter by"
- Relationships>Relationship type = "Employee of"
- Relationships>Target Contact = "The Organization you'd like to filter by"

You could set "display as" to "Contacts" (1 result per contact), or "Participants" for each individual participant record (1 result per event registration, potentially many results per contact)